# How to position inline two blocks and a span with static width between them with CSS?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

There are two blocks with content in them and one small `span` text between of them at the top. I need this `span` to have some static width like `20px` (it's `col-2` in the example) and this two blocks to split the rest of the free space.
Is this possible with **bootstrap** classes?

Here is some code: https://jsfiddle.net/Alexik/krexqp5m/1

some shorter in place:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="left-player d-inline-block col-5">
    <div class="input-group mb-2">
      <select class="form-control"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group mb-2">
      <select class="form-control w-25"></select>
      <select class="form-control"></select>
      <span class="input-group-text">
        <input type="checkbox">
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <span class="d-inline-block align-top col-2 text-center">VS</span>

  <div class="right-player d-inline-block col-5">
    <div class="input-group mb-2">
      <select class="form-control"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group mb-2">
      <select class="form-control w-25"></select>
      <select class="form-control"></select>
      <span class="input-group-text">
        <input type="checkbox">
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @Paulie_D did bro

Comment: now the question is good informative and clean. I'll appreciate if you give your upvote for it cause -2 score for question like this isn't fair at all. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can display flex property here

steps

1. set the tag inside with all the 2 divs and span are to display: flex; in my case it was body
2. give flex-grow to both the divs
3. give width to your span

css:

```
    body
    {
        display: flex;
    }
    div
    {
        flex-grow: 100;
        background-color: rgb(128, 122, 118);
    }
    span
    {
        width: 20px;
    }
```

html:

```
    <div>
        this is div one
    </div>
    <span>
        vs
    </span>
    <div>
        this is div two
    </div>
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGClZ.jpg)

I don't think bootstrap classes will work here since, their grid is divided into 12.

Answer (score 1):

With bootstrap I don't think you can do that, because it wont allow you to define exact size of that span but yes with CSS flex you can easily do that.